# How to Replace [cell] by matching other [Sheets]?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to match sheet1 col A with sheet2 colunm B.

If sheet1! A:A = sheet2! B:B

Replace Sheet1 C:C with Sheet2! D:D

I want to do that on Google spreadsheet, but don't know java much. How to do that??

```
function replaceCCWithDD(){ // in this example sheet, the function will replace sheet1 C:C from Sheet2! D:D if Sheet1! A:A matched with Sheet2! B:B

var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? Where is your 'if' condition?

Comment: If not my code.. I don't know how to code that in java/Googles app script, just started the beganing reading Google's appscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code bellow:

```
function myFunction() {
var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AjCcE3eIeB3pdFNFTUdQN1M5Rm4wOU5SSzlXb2Utc2c").getSheetByName('sheet1');
var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AjCcE3eIeB3pdFNFTUdQN1M5Rm4wOU5SSzlXb2Utc2c").getSheetByName('sheet2');

var colA = sh1.getDataRange().getValues();
var colB = sh2.getDataRange().getValues();

for(var x in colA) {    
    Logger.log(x < colB.length && colA[x][0] == colB[x][1]);
    if(x < colB.length && colA[x][0] == colB[x][1]) {         
     colA[x][2] = colB[x][3];
    }
  }  
  sh1.getDataRange().setValues(colA);
}
```

live version [here](https://script.google.com/d/1a-hFCWxZD0--rUkp6ly3hGaVrZiiwWbhzkD_9EDjdJeD3wWsXpWk6pMp/edit?usp=drive_web).

Comment: Thanks @br araujo. I'm having this error: "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 7, file "Code") what does "X" mean here?

Comment: X is the index of the colA array. Please, check if B has the same length. See the edited code